# how to find location of nans in a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a very large matrix. I need to find locations of nans (not a number) in the matrix. for example if there exists a nan in row=2 and column=5, It must give me the answer (2,5)
what do I have to do?

I searched a lot. there were answers to " how to know if any nan exist in a matrix" , but I didn't find the answer to my question.

Comment: If you had added "matlab" to your search terms, you would have gotten [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
[irow,jcol]=find(isnan(a));
```

you will get a vector of row indices in `irow`, and column indices in `jcol`.